# IS DISTINCT FROM

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe, db2-400

I'm reading over a query that performs a left outer join on itself with several on clauses. One of the on clauses is like so:

```
gl1.COLUMN1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM gl2.COLUMN1
```

How is this different from saying

```
on gl1.COLUMN1=gl2.COLUMN1
```

Comment: Consider [the manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_distinctpredicate.htm)

Answer (score 4):

IS NOT DISTINCT FROM will also return true if gl1.COLUMN1 and gl2.COLUMN2 are both null

```
select 'a' = 'a'
--true

select null = null
--null

select 'a' is not distinct from 'a'
--true

select null is not distinct from null
--true
```

Comment: as a side note, null = null evaluates to null, not false